# AWS SDK LexRuntimeService Error: JSON ParserException

Tags: php, json, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

This is for AWS LexRuntimeService SDK for PHP.
This is the full error I continue to get whenever Lex responds to the SDK with any ElicitIntent response:

> ParserException: Error parsing JSON: Syntax error in .../Aws/Api/Parser/PayloadParserTrait.php on line 20

ElicitSlot does not cause this exception error.

I cannot find a way to view exactly what JSON object or string is being parsed and causing the error.
But when I use the Lex test chat bot, and trigger the same response as what should be returned to the SDK, I notice that the JSON difference between the intent that is working and the other intents that cause this error is a null in the IntentName field. However, when I try to provide an intentName to ElicitIntent, the Lex bot errors on receiving intentName. So lex outputs null intentName for ElicitIntent directives.

See here:

---

Initiate BookRide Intent with input = "book a ride".
Lex JSON Response =

```
{
  "dialogState": "ElicitSlot",
  "intentName": "BookRide",
  "message": "Hi. Where are you going?",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": "address",
  "slots": null
}
```

SDK RESULT = PASS. NO ERROR.

---

Trigger other intents: Input = "hello", "thanks", "help"
(other intents all trigger ElicitIntent, but with different messages)
Lex JSON Response =

```
{
  "dialogState": "ElicitIntent",
  "intentName": null,
  "message": "Hello. I can help you order a ride. Just ask, book me a ride, to get started.",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": null,
  "slots": null
}
```

SDK RESULT = ERROR: `ParserException: Error parsing JSON: Syntax error`

---

This is the code that passes messages to my Lex bot using PostContent.

```
$credentials = new \Aws\Credentials\Credentials('XXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');

$args = array(
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'debug' => true,
    'credentials' => $credentials
);

$lex_client = new Aws\LexRuntimeService\LexRuntimeServiceClient($args);

$lex_response = $lex_client->postContent([
    'accept' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'botAlias' => 'XXXX',
    'botName' => 'XXXX',
    'contentType' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
    'inputStream' => $userInput,
    'requestAttributes' => array(),
    'sessionAttributes' => array(),
    'userId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
]);
```

Any ideas what is causing the ParseException?
Or how I can view the details of what causes the ParseException to be thrown?

---

UPDATE:
This does not solve the problem but just tried using `postText` instead of `postContent`and `ElicitIntent` directives work fine!
So this error is limited to `postContent` in the SDK.

Comment: Have you tried to create a local unit test (phpunit, behat, &c) to launch this code? It would allow you to crank up debug output or to connect a debugger to the executing code and to step through it. It is hard for us to debug without seeing the code that causes this exception.

Comment: @EpicVoyage I've added the code used to send a user's message from the SDK to the Lex bot: `$lex_response = $lex_client->postContent(...)` But when receiving the JSON response from Lex, it is the SDK that throws the Parsing error. So I'd love to be able to step through the SDK's execution of handling the `postContent` response, if you know how to do that?